# x86 loope/z instruction should be sign extended according to address size prefix

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

Hey I'm wondering if the `LOOPE` `LOOPZ` instructions should be sign extended by the address size prefix.

In the intel manual it's written:

> Performs a loop operation using the RCX, ECX or CX register as a
> counter (depending on whether address size is 64 bits, 32 bits, or 16
> bits). Note that the LOOP instruction ignores REX.W; but 64-bit
> address size can be over-ridden using a 67H prefix.

**Operation**

```
IF (AddressSize = 32)
    THEN Count is ECX;
ELSE IF (AddressSize = 64)
    Count is RCX;
ELSE Count is CX;
FI;
```

Now I understand what register we use for counting will be dependent on the address size prefix, but nothing on the validity of the assembly written is mentioned, seeing disassemblers output like objdump and others yields for the current stream of bytes `67 e1 d2` the following output

```
0:  67 e1 d2                addr32 loope 0xffffffffffffffd5
```

I thought it should extend the immediate to the size of the counter so it should have looked something like this:

```
0:  67 e1 d2                addr32 loope 0xffffffd5
```

So I'm basically just asking about the validity of the assembly on how it should be written depending on the mode of operation (bitness).

Comment: Note that some versions of objdump will disassemble as `loopel`

Comment: The address size prefix has no effect on the interpretation of the branch destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate is the branch target ***DEST**ination*, a pc-relative encoding of the distance to branch, should the branch be taken.  Positive values indicate forward branching in the instruction stream and negative values indicate backward branching.

The branch condition is whether the designated register is zero or not; that register (some version of `cx`) is not sign extended — it is just compared with zero.

The sign extension is of the branch target immediate has the effect of determining whether the branch is forward or backward.  The size of the branch target immediate is not determined by the size prefix — the size prefix determines the register width to use in the compare with zero.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'm wondering if I have the following stream at vma 0, `\xe0\x7e` should it be sign extended since `7e + 2 = 80` which has its msb on? I see disassembler treat it as not sign extended as if testing the msb before calculating the offset to the instruction pointer

Comment: The calculation 0x7e+0x02 = 0x80, where — if each is taken as signed 8 bits — is 8-bit signed arithmetic overflow, which is not really useful.  What the processor does instead is sign extend the immediate to full size first, then add to RIP+2 in full size. Thus, here 8-bit 0x7e => 64-bit 0x000000000000007e, then 64-bit 0x000000000000007e + RIP + 0000000000000002 (which ends up being RIP+0x080, of course). That's what the disassembler should be telling you. However, there are others here that are far more knowledgeable on x86/x64 encodings, so consider maybe asking as a new question, as needed.